# how to store azure PAT in vscode so I do not have to provide it manually

Tags: git, azure

In my company we abanodoned TFS and started using GIT (finally). Although, I have question about storing PAT somewhere so I do not have to provide it manually every time.

We are using azure devOps, and vscode, but with every pull or push I have to provide this impossible to remember complex string. How can I make vs code/git remember it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to [Use Git Credential Manager to authenticate to Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops)

Make sure to have the Git Credential Manager installed (it comes with the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

> When you connect to a Git repository from your Git client for the first time, the credential manager prompts for credentials.
> Provide your Microsoft account or Azure AD credentials.